# What option suppresses axes, ticks and labels in gridIIID?

Tags: pstricks, pst-solides3d

I am interested in using the `\gridIIID` command but I don't want the box to have ticks, labels or axes

I found the following line in the changelog:

`4.20 2010-07-23  - activate keyword planmarks for gridIIID for supprsssing ticks and labels (hv)`

does this mean that the options have not been implemented?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=20 40 20,Decran=30}
\defFunction[algebraic]{curva3D}(t){cos(2*t)}{sin(t)}{t}
\defFunction[algebraic]{curvaXZ}(t){cos(2*t)}{-3}{t}
\defFunction[algebraic]{curvaYZ}(t){-4}{sin(t)}{t}
\psset{object=courbe,range=-2 2,r=0,resolution=360}
\psSolid[function=curvaXZ,linecolor=gray]
\psSolid[function=curvaYZ,linecolor=gray]
\psSolid[
    function=curva3D,
    linecolor=blue,
    linewidth=2pt
]
\gridIIID[Zmin=-2,Zmax=2,axisnames={,,},labels=none,ticks=none](-4,4)(-3,3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

And an image for anyone wondering

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\gridIIID[Zmin=-2,Zmax=2,planmarks=false,showAxes=false](-4,4)(-3,3)     
\axesIIID[axisnames={,,}](3,4,3)(6,7,4)
```

Comment: that is awesome. One thing though, the axes are still sticking out, and `z` is ridiculously long. Is there anyway to remove this as well? I was also thinking about painting the cube manually but that just complicates things...

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I need to remove the axes, not add a new set of them per your fix. There is a set of axes created with `gridIIID`. I wanted to remove/supress the axes, because I don't want anymore clutter. Is this posible?

Comment: Don't use `\axesIII` if you do not want axes.

Comment: `gridIIID` already adds a set of axes. Are these axes removable/supressable?

Comment: I already suppressed the axes with `showAxes=false`!!

Comment: Darnit!!!!! i didn't copy it correctly. I'm sorry my bad. The result is absolutely wonderful. Is there any way to make contributions to the documentation of pst-solides3d?

Comment: @hanzo2001: What is `darnit`? Did you mean `dammit`?

Comment: I guess so, but that is out of the scope of this conversation. :/